# Should I submit an ajax call on change, focus or neither for a drop down using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a regular select list.

```
<select name="pets">
    <option>Dog</select>
    <option>Cat</select>
</select>
```

Once the selected item has changed, I need to spawn off an ajax call to update a value. My problem is, if a user uses the keyboard to shuffle through the values, the change event is fired a bunch. Thus meaning many ajax calls to the server. That approach doesn't seem right to me.

If I use blur or focus, the user could change the value, and their next click could take them to a separate page, never allowing the ajax request to finish.

I'm not certain the best way to handle this sort of situation.

Comment: The Ajax call is asynchronous, so it would finish. The results might not be displayed because the user is on a different page.

Comment: You could disable the select when you begin the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to slightly delay your AJAX call, for example a second, if the user changes it again within that time, you clear the previous interval, and set a new one, and so forth.

If the selection seem to be stable, then your AJAX call will happen.

See here for an example on how to use these methods. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do ajax call only after some time of user inactivity.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XcDnU/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;
    $('select').change(function(){
        var self = this;
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
            delayedOnChange.apply(self, arguments);
        }, 300);
    });
    var delayedOnChange = function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
        // ajax call here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On `.blur` would be your best option.
Most browsers lock up until the requests are done when performing synchronous ajax requests. If you don't need that syncing handshake between your server page and the jquery, you won't be using this anyway.

By default, ajax requests in jquery are asynchronous and once you fire off your request you don't have to stick around and wait for a response.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/